# Google Sheets - extract numbers before/after or between specific text or characters

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**I need a formula that extracts numbers only from a cell which includes these numbers and other characters.**
I've tried several different formulas, but they yield different results.
The problem is that I can only get the values I want if the number is first in the list. If it's between different characters I also get what comes before the value I need to be extracted.

```
+-------------------+
|       Data        |
+-------------------+
| 5cats/3dogs       |
| 5cats/3pigs       |
| 5pigs/2dogs/6cats |
| 12dogs/3cats      |
+-------------------+
```

I'm really new to Google Sheets, so I only came to the current formula after searching a few threads on this forum, so any further help and guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep that in mind next time!

Comment: Please keep in mind that you should also show what you've tried. Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your basic formula to this simple one for each column

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A7="",, 
   IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A7,"dogs"), REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A7,"(\d+)dogs"),0)))
```

*(**Do adjust** the formula according to your ranges and delete everything under it)*

[image]

Comment: I really like this one! While other suggested formulas seem to work as well, this one looks pretty simple and easy for me to follow and adjust to my other needs, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY(
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A5, "\d+", ), "/")&"×"&
 SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A5, "(?:)[a-z]+", ), "/")&"×"&ROW(A2:A5)), "×"), 
 "select max(Col2) where Col3 is not null group by Col3 pivot Col1"), 
 "select Col2,Col1,Col3 offset 1", )*1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic spill array you may try below formula-

```
=BYROW($A$2:$A,LAMBDA(x,IF(x="",,IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(FLATTEN(SPLIT(x,"/")),"select * where Col1 like '%" & LOWER(H$1) & "%'"),"\d+"),0))))
```

See you workbook sheet name `harun24hr`.

[image]

> Edit: Based on formula from @marikamitsos answer you can use-

```
=BYROW($A$2:$A,LAMBDA(x,IFERROR(IF(x="",,REGEXEXTRACT(x,"(\d+)"&LOWER(K$1))),0)))
```

[image]

Comment: @Oldy delete "(correct formula)" to get the result.